# Using Annotated in FastAPI ignores rules set in Query

Tags: python, fastapi, python-typing

I'm starting to learn Python and FastAPI but I encountered a weird thing. When I set

```
@app.get("/test")
async def test(q: str = Query(min_length=3)):
    return q
```

it correctly checks if q has at least 3 characters, but when I do it as suggested in docs

```
@app.get("/test")
async def test(q: Annotated[str, Query(min_length=3)]):
    return q
```

it ignores the `min_length` rule and only checks if q is present, is there any reason why it happens? I'm using Python 3.10.10 and FastAPI 0.94.1

Comment: Oh good gosh, what a timing to start learning FastAPI... you're totally right, I didn't find this one, the docs are already recommending Annotated, but current release is still 0.94.1, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue. The `Annotate` feature only works in [FastAPI version 0.95+](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/pull/4871#issuecomment-1474518234).

Just do

```
pip install --upgrade fastapi
```

to upgrade to the latest version. That should solve the problem.